# Unable to ping or use VPN when connected to a 5G router

Tags: router, vpn, internet, ping

I am using a Zyxel FWA510 router. It's a 5G router and I use my Telekom 5G sim with it.
After I start up the router and connect my Laptop (Macbook Pro 2021) through wifi with it. I cannot do the following things:

1. I am unable to `ping 8.8.8.8`
2. I am unable to connect to my Work VPN
3. I am unable to use my personal VPN software either

This is really frustrating. Is a port blocked that should be open? Do I need to disable IPv6?

I tried turning on the IPSec passthrough setting, but that did not work either. What should I do?

Comment: Do you have to pay a VPN upgrade charge? I do for my HUAWEI card

Comment: I don't have such a thing for my Sim card or the router software.

Comment: It is an ISP thing. Perhaps talk to them. That is what I had to do.

Comment: Could you give some more details please? Like will they give me a different APN on which these services run smoothly? Or will they enable things on their end for you? How was it on your case?

Comment: I asked my ISP why VPN would not work and they said I had to pay monthly ($5) to accommodate  VPN addressing. VPN worked after that . So I suggest you try the same.

Comment: I stress that you should ask the ISP in case that is not the reason for not having VPN.